# Load a key from a properties file in spring context dynamically

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to load a key (has a value) in the properties file dynamically. This is what am trying to do. I have two app servers A & B. And there is a quartz job that runs for every one hour in both the servers, which is causing some problems. To solve this, I would like to set a key in the properties file with server name (say serverA, serverB) and when I pass the quartz schedule to the cronbean (in spring xml) the value I should pass (which is the key from the properties file) should be dynamic. I mean, if hostname is server A, then the value from serverA should be loaded from properties file and the same with server B. Below is the snippet -

```
**application-host.xml - Initialized hostname in spring context**

<bean id="hostname" factory-bean="localhost" factory-method="getHostName"/>
<bean id="localhost" class="java.net.InetAddress" factory-method="getLocalHost"/>

**application-quartz.xml - Place where am loading the quartz schedule**

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="job" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${  serverA / serverB  }" /> ** THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SET OR LOAD PROPERTIES FROM THE FILE, BASED ON THE HOST NAME.
</bean>

**env-test.properties**

serverA = 0 0 3 * * ?
serverB = 0 0 5 * * ?
```

I knew other ways, such as updating the properties file with different schedules before starting up the app server, but this is a little risky as there is a chance to miss during the deployment process. Appreciate if you can help me find a better solution or answer this one.

Thanks, Sirish.

Comment: Why don't you use different properties files which include both the hostname and cronexpression for serverA and serverB?

Comment: @Marcelo - Yes, but this creates lot of properties files. I would love to fit all of these in a single properties file, per environment and load the key I wanted based on the host name (as described above).

Comment: I understand your need, I just think it is wrong, you basically want to have all your deployment configurations in one single file. For your needs, look into http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html